# Watir problem: ECONNABORTED

Tags: watir, firewatir

I happily use Watir (actually, FireWatir) on 3 computers.
Only on one of them I get frequently this issue:

```
C:/Program Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/firewatir-1.6.7/lib/firewatir/jssh_socket.rb:63:in `recv': An established connection was aborte d by the software in your host machine. - recvfrom(2) (Errno::ECONNABORTED)
```

This happens at random moments during a script.
What is the cause, and what can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when running an exceptionally long test using Mechanize as the browser.  I believe it points to a memory error/overflow, or network overflow, but I have not been able to confirm it.